# How to dynamically inject components/fields into a dummy page using vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to create a dummy vue page, were the different components used in the page like b-field ,b-table etc should be injected into the page in order to make things more dynamic. Currently the fields and components are defined in the template section of the .vue page.

```
<template>
  <div class="container is-fluid">
    <b-loading :is-full-page="true" :active.sync="this.isLoading"></b-loading>
    <p class="subtitle">Business Unit</p>
    <b-field label="Business Unit">
      <b-input
        required
        :disabled="this.newRecord ? false : true"
        :value="this.objectData.id"
        @input="(newValue)=>{updateValue(newValue,'id')}"
      ></b-input>
    </b-field>
    <b-field label="Description">
      <b-input
        :value="this.objectData.description"
        @input="(newValue)=>{updateValue(newValue,'description')}"
      ></b-input>
    </b-field>
    <b-field label="Short Description">
      <b-input
        :value="this.objectData.shortdescription"
        @input="(newValue)=>{updateValue(newValue,'shortdescription')}"
      ></b-input>
    </b-field>
    <b-field label="Status">
      <b-autocomplete
        :value="this.objectData.status"
        :open-on-focus="true"
        :keep-first="true"
        :data="['Active','InActive']"
        @input="(newValue)=>{updateValue(newValue,'status')}"
       ></b-autocomplete>
    </b-field>   

    <section>
      <p class="is-size-7 has-text-danger">{{submitError}}</p>      
      <b-button @click="submitForm" class="is-radiusless">Submit</b-button>
      <b-button type="is-text" @click="$router.go(-1)" class="is-radiusless">Return</b-button>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { viewMixin } from "../viewMixin.js";
const ViewName = "BusinessUnitDetail";
export default {
  name: "BusinessUnitDetail",
   mixins: [viewMixin(ViewName)],
};
</script>
```

But the components mentioned in the template section should actually be stored as a string and going forward in the future this string will be retrieved from the database instead. But for the time being and as a starting point , this string can be hardcoded in the script section itself. Now i need a solution or guidance on how to achieve this and make the page to actually work..

**Note:** Please note that in vue js, i know that we could show or hide components based on the application state using  Vue conditional structures such as v-if and v-else. But this is not what iam talking about. Instead i want the components (b-field,b-table etc) to be dynamically injected into the DOM. So in future if there will be an extra b-field or any other component, i can  simply append the component tag to the string and that new component will be rendered in the frontend successfully.Plz help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution you look for is [vue dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

So you can do this:

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) of components" :key="index">
   <component :is="item.name" :any-prop="item.anyProp">
</template>

...
<script>
// ...
data() {
  return {
    components: [
      { name: 'b-field', anyProp: 'status' }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i still din't fully understand ? Can you show me an example for   <b-field label="Business Unit">
      <b-input
        required
        :disabled="this.newRecord ? false : true"
        :value="this.objectData.id"
        @input="(newValue)=>{updateValue(newValue,'id')}"
      ></b-input>
    </b-field>

Comment: if the b-field tag itself will be stored as string then how can this be injected into the page?

Comment: With this solution, you can dynamically instanciate a component based on the name provided. Then it behaves like the normal component (with props, slots etc.). But it can be hard to maintain if you have a lot of possibilites here.

I'd suggest to look into the `render` function in Vue (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), which is a more advanced way to template your component with js code instead of html.

I can't provide you a working solution for your case since it's a bit complex!

Comment: ok i will try your solution but i am a little confused on how the attributes and events of a components like  (:value ,:data , '@input', '@focus' etc) will be dynamically set ? Do we have to pass them up as props?

Comment: You have to pass props as for every regular components. If some props diverge from the different components, they will be ignored (because your component don't need these props).